# Linq to Entities Join on two substrings (one via a navigation property) with a Cross Apply (Method Syntax)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

Trying to join two tables on two substrings all while performing a cross apply:

```
            var thisQuery = ctx.Table1
                .Join(ctx.Table2,
                    t1 => t1.t1NavigationProperty1.SelectMany(t1n1 => t1n1.n1NavigationProperty2.t1n1n2Field1.Substring(0, 13)),
                    t2 => t2.t2Field2.Substring(0, 13)
                    (t1, t2) => new { t1, t2 })
                .SelectMany(t1t2 => t1t2.t2
                    .OrderByDescending(t1t2.t2.NullableDateTime)
                    .Take(1)
                );
```

I'm getting errors about using substrings in the join and I also need to perform the cross apply without using a SelectMany.

Comment: `CROSS APPLY` can be expressed in EF Core only via `SelectMany`.